# Is for loop in a view function problematic?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, optimization

I have a smart contract that has an array of keys and a mapping from that key to a struct which keeps information, and a mapping from user to array of keys, as follows:

```
contract C {
  struct Info {
    uint x;
    string y;
  }

  uint[] keys;
  mapping (uint => Info) public keyToInfo;
  mapping (address => uint[]) userToKeyList;
 
  function getAllInfo() public view returns (Info[] memory allInfo) {
    allInfo = new Info[](keys.length);
    for (uint i = 0; i < allInfo.length; ++i) {
      allInfo[i] = keyToInfo[keys[i]];
    }
  }

  function getInfoOf(address _user) public view returns (Info[] memory allInfo) {
    allInfo = new Info[](userToKeyList[_user].length);
    for (uint i = 0; i < allInfo.length; ++i) {
      allInfo[i] = keyToInfo[userToKeyList[_user][i]];
    }
  }
}
```

I am aware that for loops can cause problems evespecially if the array is large. What can I do to optimally implement this functionality? For instance, is only returning the key array, and then from the frontend, sending request for each key's corresponding info is better? Any help and comment is appreciated.